# Match with toObjectId in mongodb Aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, objectid

Really stuck with something that to me seems like it should be easy

I want to essentially do is convert the string of an objectId to an objectId and match on that, but I can't figure out how to do it...!

**To be clear**, I can't use `{ x: ObjectId(someObjectId) }` because I'm wanting to serialise the query to JSON

Data:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f37eaaae4102600180078a8"
  },
  "Details": "Something A",
  "App": {
    "$oid": "5f37cec069106932d4710ea6"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f3860f10a9db00018f2e2e3"
  },
  "Details": "Something B",
  "App": {
    "$oid": "5f37cec069106932d4710ea6"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f3908a7db8fd70018b19942"
  },
  "Details": "Something C",
  "App": {
    "$oid": "5f37cec069106932d4710ea7"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f390961db8fd70018b19945"
  },
  "Details": "Something D",
  "App": {
    "$oid": "5f37cec069106932d4710ea8"
  }
}
]
```

And query with something like:

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'App': {
        '$eq': {
          '$toObjectId': '5f37cec069106932d4710ea8'
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the result obviously being:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f390961db8fd70018b19945"
  },
  "Details": "Something D",
  "App": {
    "$oid": "5f37cec069106932d4710ea8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          "$App",
          {
            "$toObjectId": "5f37cec069106932d4710ea8"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ONWmcy3DCcf)

Comment: That doesn't work because I'm serialising the hardcoded query and ObjectId doesn't work if its serialised, so I need to be able to store it as JSON, hence the string to objectId :-)

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try it now?